# false elliptic curves and principal polarizations

Tags: abelian-varieties, shimura-varieties, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Hi,

Let $\Delta$ be a quaternion algebra over $\mathbf Q$ and let $\mathcal O_\Delta$ be a maximal order in $\Delta$.
Recall that a *false elliptic curve* over a field $K$ is a pair $(A/K,i)$ consisting
of an abelian surface $A/K$ and a ring homomorphism $i : \mathcal O_\Delta\to End_K(A)$.
Suppose that $\Delta$ is indefinite, i.e., $\Delta\otimes\mathbf R \simeq M_2(\mathbf R)$. There is an involution $*:\Delta\to\Delta$ that coincides with taking transpose under the
previous isomorphism. It is well-known (easy?) that if $K$ is of characteristic zero there is a polarization of $A/K$ such that the corresponding Rosatti involution in $End_K(A)\otimes\mathbf Q$ corresponds to $* : \Delta\to\Delta$ by $i$. Moreover, this polarization is unique up to a rational number.

Question 1: is it possible to find a (necessarily unique) principal polarization with this property?

Question 2: is it possible to find such a (principal) polarization over a field $K$ of non-zero characteristic?

Thanks!